# How to set locale in ng datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I am using Angular 6 ,

My Html is

```
<ng-datepicker required class="date-picker" name="durationStart" #durationStart="ngModel"
   [(ngModel)]="lounge.crossSellServiceDate" [options]="dateOptions"></ng-datepicker>
```

And in my .ts file

```
this.dateOptions.locale=Object.assign({}, {locale: this.localeService.locale});
console.log(this.dateOptions);
```

which is setting locale very well as

[image: Locale set as zh-Hans]

But calendar is still showing in English .

This code i get from [this Github post](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2607)

What wrong is going on here , how to change calender language as per app locale ?

**Update 1**

after

```
import localeEN from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localezhHant from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hant';
import localezhHans from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hans';
```

and in constructor

```
if(this.localeService.locale!='en')
{
this.dateOptions.locale = Object.assign({}, localezhHans);
console.log(this.dateOptions);
}
```

Now i am able to set chines locale , as i can see in console

[image: Chinese Locale]

But calendar still reflecting content in English

Comment: Have you imported these import { zhCn } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale'; ? as per the github post.

Comment: look for the SidekickJohn  post , he is setting as string

Comment: Just try importing it and then use it .

Comment: ok , let me try

Comment: Tried , but not working

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth , see update 1

Comment: Hope I can help you. [link]( https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/demo/src/app/components/datepicker/demos/i18n)

Comment: @Hoàngg Thanks , but its not ng-bootstrap-datepicker , its ng2-datepicker